# Emails Going To Spam And Cant Receive Emails VestaCP

Tags: email, phpmailer, ubuntu-16.04, exim, vesta

i am trying to setup mails on my VestaCP, i have made MX, Dmarc records, followed every guide about these records on google but there are 2 problems.

Here is my mxtoolbox results
https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/letsupload.co/

```
                                        =======
```

1st Problem -/

The first problem is that all my mails sent from contact@letsupload.co are sent into spam folders, though i created all required records.

2nd Problem -/

I can send emails from my webmail but i cant receive them, when i send email from gmail it gets sent, there is no error that my email was not delivered but i dont receive it in my webmail.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that not many people will help because of the lack of code. Just always make sure that when you ask a question like this wondering why something isn't working, you provide code so people can pin point a problem. Stack Overflow don't put that page there before you ask a question because they think you're stupid, they do it so you can get a more specific and the best response to your question. [So just make sure you give this a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

**However**, I had a similar issue before where all my mails were being sent to the spam folder and they're a few things that could be the cause:

- **Mail Client Reverse DNS Checks:** You mentioned that you are using a personal domain but one thing to remember is that your domain will have its on DNS server.*e.g. if you are with GoDaddy that would be the default DNS setting*. **So the problem is** that when you send an email to lets say a @outlook.com email server the mail client of the recipient will do a reverse DNS check. So it realises that you are sending to an **@outlook.com** but the email is coming from **@letsupload.co**. So it realises that you are sending from an IP that isn't related to the domain you sending to and **that is what SPAM is!** Like I said without seeing your code I can't exactly know how to help but if you aren't aready using a mail server with Authentication enabled that could be a cause. Try using a server with authentication and add this code:

  ```
  // I am using $mail as my instance of PHPMailer
  $mail->Host = 'your-new-server-with-authentication';
  $mail->Port = 587; // usually the default port (double check though)
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  // now define the username and password for your mail server
  $mail->Username = 'your-username@mailserver.com';
  $mail->Password = 'OpenSesame123';
  ```
- **Reply to:** You can also try adding a reply-to email address. Some mail servers tend to put emails in spam that don't have a reply email address to stop bots from spamming a person's email account. So try adding this if you haven't already:

  ```
  // I am using $mail as my instance of the PHPMailer
  $mail->AddReplyTo('youremail@domain.com');
  ```
- **Implementing SPF:** If the above to fail then the chances are that you need to implement SPF. You can learn all about this from an expert on the subject **gr8gonzo** [here is the tutorial and article he wrote on the subject](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/A_1222-16-Tips-to-Improve-Email-Delivery.html). That will not only just help with implementing SPF but also with the best practises for when you're sending emails.

Comment: Thank you for replying me Mwikala, sorry for not providing enough information, the reason for that is i am newbie. I have setup the records properly, such as DKIM, PTR SPF and everything and in mxtoolbox they all are alright,

About setting up the mailserver, i quite dont understand sorry for that. I am using VestaCP and create all my mails in that panel, Please ask for any information or code i can provide that.

Comment: That's alright. Why don't you have a look at this post: https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4377

Comment: Thank you, i just had to add include:_spf.google.com in my SPF record, which fixed the problem, it was stated in the above link you provided. Thanks :D